# General sum of $n$th roots of unity raised to power $m$ comprime with $n$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to find a reference for the following proposition:

Let $m$ and $n$ be coprime. Then, 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \exp\left( i \frac{2\pi}{n} k m \right) = 0 $$
if and only if $r$ is an integer multiple of $n$.

Can anyone point a basic textbook or online material in which this basic fact is proven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be proven easily using geometric summation. Observe that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \exp\left(i \frac{2\pi k m}{n} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \exp(2\pi i m/n)^k = \frac{1-\exp(2\pi i m/n)^r}{1-\exp(2\pi i m/n)}
$$
The sum is $0$ if and only if $\exp(2\pi i m/n)^r = 1$, which corresponds to $n|rm$.

Comment: Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Summation

Comment: Neat :) Thanks.